# git fetch return different branches each time

Tags: git

I am a newbie with Git and made some funny mistake here. I don't remember how exactly I got it, but this is what I have now: I have two branches, namely master and Master. Each time I fetch from my server, one of them is returned (by turn) and the branch history is slightly different. Yet, the latest branch is always Master. Here is the illustration [result](http://i57.tinypic.com/2cdygdh.jpg). 
How may I delete the master branch on server? Much appreciated!

Comment: Are you on an operating system which is case insensitive (that is, Mac or Windows)?

Comment: Yes. This is why the system tries to prevent me from deleting the current branch, as it thinks I am deleting "Master" instead of "master", isn't it? In any case, I logged onto the server and deleted the branch folder to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following.
To delete a local branch

```
    git branch -d local_branch
```

To remove a remote branch

```
   git push origin :remote_branch
```

Comment: Thanks. But git requires me to set receive.denyDeleteCurrent. I tried but couldn't get through. Should I do that on my PC on the server? What would be the correct command? (my "git config receive.denyDeleteCurrent warn" makes no difference)

Comment: You should delete the obsolete branch on the server using "git push origin :name_of_branch" command on your local computer.

Comment: Thanks. In the end, I chopped it off on the server to dodge case sensitivity all together and lived happy ever after.